# Python remove items from list

Tags: python, list, items

I'm having some troubles with removing items from a list. I'm looking for a more elegant solution. Preferably a solution in one for-loop or filter.

The objective of the piece of code: remove all empty entries and all entries starting with a '#' from the config handle.

At the moment i'm using:

```
# Read the config file and put every line in a seperate entry in a list
configHandle = [item.rstrip('\n') for item in open('config.conf')]

# Strip comment items from the configHandle
for item in configHandle:
    if item.startswith('#'):
        configHandle.remove(item)

# remove all empty items in handle
configHandle = filter(lambda a: a != '', configHandle)
print configHandle
```

This works but I think it is a bit of a nasty solution.

When I try:

```
# Read the config file and put every line in a seperate entry in a list
configHandle = [item.rstrip('\n') for item in open('config.conf')]

# Strip comment items and empty items from the configHandle
for item in configHandle:
    if item.startswith('#'):
        configHandle.remove(item)
    elif len(item) == 0:
        configHandle.remove(item)
```

This, however, fails. I cannot figure out why.

Can someone push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Because You're changing the list while iterating over it. You can use a list comprehension to get ride of this problem:

```
configHandle = [i for i in configHandle if i and not i.startswith('#')]
```

Also for opening a file you better to use a `with` statement that close the file at the end of the block automatically<sup>1</sup>:

```
with open('config.conf') as infile :
   configHandle = infile.splitlines()
   configHandle = [line for line in configHandle if line and not line.startswith('#')]
```

---

<sub>1. Because there is no guarantee for external links to be collected by garbage-collector. And you need to close them explicitly, which can be done by calling the `close()` method of a file object, or as mentioned as a more pythonic way use a `with` statement.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I do not understand the first solution (using a comprehension) completely. How does that line else remove the empty entries in the list? Because this also does the trick for me configHandle = [i for i in configHandle if len(i)>0 and not i.startswith('#')]

Comment: @DCB When you write `if line` python checks the validity of `line` if it evaluate as True python run your condition, and in this case an empty string  evaluates as False. Read more here https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Answer (score 1):

Don't remove items while you iterating, it's a common pitfall

Answer (score 0):

You aren't allowed to modify an item that you're iterating over.

Instead you should use things like `filter` or list comprehensions.

```
configHandle = filter(lambda a: (a != '') and not a.startswith('#'), configHandle)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `filter` expression is good; just include the additional condition you're looking for:

```
configHandle = filter(lambda a: a != '' and not a.startswith('#'), configHandle)
```

There are other options if you don't want to use `filter`, but, as has been stated in other answers, it is a very bad idea to attempt to modify a list while you are iterating through it. The answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python) stackoverflow question provides alternatives to using `filter` to remove from a list based on a condition.